# Cucumber-cpp step defiinition runner exits immediately

Tags: boost, cmake, cucumber, googletest, cucumber-cpp

Based on the instructions given at [cucumber-cpp github repo](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-cpp) and [cucumber-cpp step definition quick-start guide](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-cpp/wiki/Primer) , I created my cucumber step definition files. The features and their step_definition files are under `features/` folder, and the cpp code is built with cucumber-cpp headers and linked against libcucumber-cpp.a as instructed.

Cucumber step definition runners should stay running as a seperate process and cucumber command should execute while the runner is running. Indeed, the examples in the cucumber-cpp repository execute like that, but when I create my own step definitions, with gtest or boost test, they execute immediately, without waiting for calls from cucumber.

```
Onats-MacBook-Pro:bin onatbas$ ./tests/AdditionTest_TESTTARGET 
Running main() from gtest_main.cc
[==========] Running 0 tests from 0 test cases.
[==========] 0 tests from 0 test cases ran. (0 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 0 tests.
Onats-MacBook-Pro:bin onatbas$
```

Instead of executing immediately, it should say nothing and wait for cucumber calls. I copy-pasted the example code from the cucumber-cpp into my project and they, too, exit immediately. So even though there's no source code difference between cucumber-cpp's examples and mine, they act differently. 
I suspected the cmake build scripts might be linking with different libraries, but the linkage process is exactly the same too.

Does anybody have any idea on why this might be happening?

Here's the repository with minimum code that reproduces the error I have. https://github.com/onatbas/CucumberCppTest
The complete trace is at readme.

The cucumber files are under `features/`, and ther's only one feature that's identical to what's [here](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-cpp/tree/master/examples/Calc)

The runner executable is defined in `tests/CMakeLists.txt`

---

For quick reference: Here's the step-definition file 
AdditionTest.cxx

```
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
#include <cucumber-cpp/defs.hpp>

#include <CucumberApp.hxx>

using cucumber::ScenarioScope;

struct CalcCtx {
    Calculator calc;
    double result;
};

GIVEN("^I have entered (\\d+) into the calculator$") {
    REGEX_PARAM(double, n);
    ScenarioScope<CalcCtx> context;

    context->calc.push(n);
}

WHEN("^I press add") {
    ScenarioScope<CalcCtx> context;

    context->result = context->calc.add();
}

WHEN("^I press divide") {
    ScenarioScope<CalcCtx> context;

    context->result = context->calc.divide();
}

THEN("^the result should be (.*) on the screen$") {
    REGEX_PARAM(double, expected);
    ScenarioScope<CalcCtx> context;

    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(expected, context->result);
}
```

and here's the tests/CMakeLists.txt file where the executable is added.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

find_package(Threads)
set(CUCUMBERTEST_TEST_DEPENDENCIES cucumberTest
    ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT} 
    ${GTEST_BOTH_LIBRARIES}
    ${GMOCK_BOTH_LIBRARIES}
    ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT}
    ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
    ${CUCUMBER_BINARIES} 
)

macro(ADD_NEW_CUCUMBER_TEST TEST_SOURCE FOLDER_NAME)
    set (TARGET_NAME ${TEST_SOURCE}_TESTTARGET)
    add_executable(${TARGET_NAME} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/features/step_definitions/${TEST_SOURCE})
    target_link_libraries(${TARGET_NAME} ${CUCUMBERTEST_TEST_DEPENDENCIES})
    add_test(NAME ${TEST_SOURCE} COMMAND ${TARGET_NAME})
    set_property(TARGET ${TARGET_NAME} PROPERTY FOLDER ${FOLDER_NAME})
endmacro()

ADD_NEW_CUCUMBER_TEST(AdditionTest  "cucumberTest_tests")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example outputs

```
Running main() from gtest_main.cc
```

That main method will run the test runner's default behaviour instead of Cucumber-CPP's. The main mathod that you want (`src/main.cpp`) is included as part of the compiled cucumber-cpp library.

Try moving `${CUCUMBER_BINARIES}` in `CUCUMBERTEST_TEST_DEPENDENCIES` before all others, or linking to testing libraries that do not contain a main method (e.g. GoogleTest ships with two libraries: one with and one without the main method).

Comment: Thank you, initially when I tried that, boost linker errors turned me into thinking I was doing something wrong. It seems I didn't link with some boost libraries. So, what I did is, first moved CUCUMBER_BINARIES in the CUCUMBER_TEST_DEPENDENCIES to upmost place, second, I added these boost targets in configure_boost.cmake, chrono and program_options in addition to others. 

Now it works like a charm and correct main method is linked, indeed. 
Thanks!

I will commit the latest version and leave it working for future references.